# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite3

Надо изменить значение в таблице через функцию, но вылезает ошибка

> ```
> self.cursor.execute("UPDATE settings SET ? = ? WHERE peer_id = ?", 
> (column, value, peer_id))
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
> ```

Код функции прилагаю.

```
def update_settings(self, peer_id, column, value):
        """"Обновляем настройки беседы"""
        self.cursor.execute("UPDATE settings SET ? = ? WHERE peer_id = ?", (column, value, peer_id))
        return self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: для указания имени столбца не могут использоваться плейсхолдеры. попробуйте отдельным выражением вставить имя столбца в строку, а уже её отправлять в `execute`

Comment: `query = f"UPDATE settings SET {column} = {value} WHERE peer_id = {peer_id}"
self.cursor.execute(query)`
Вы так имеете ввиду?

Comment: Не совсем `query = f"UPDATE settings SET {column} = ? WHERE peer_id = ?"; self.cursor.execute(query, (value, peer_id))`, т.к. значения всё-таки безопаснее добавлять через плейсхолдеры. Только безопасность такого использования имени столбца Вы полностью берете на себя